# SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field - In visual force Commanlink action

Tags: visualforce

I am having issues with Merge fields not working with the visualforce page I created.

This is the code where it is having issue;

```
<apex:commandLink target="_blank" action="https://na99.salesforce.com/a2g/e?CF00N0A000000Okji={!Account_Plans__c.Name}" value="New Key Business Initiative"/>
```

It is not querying this field; CF00N0A000000Okji={!Account_Plans__c.Name}

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The error means you're trying to access something that you didn't include in the query. Most probably, you have not included Name field in the query for Account_Plans__c in your controller.

Make sure you have included the field when you are referring it.

> The error
>   "SObject-row-was-retrieved-via-SOQL-without-querying-the-requested-field"
>   can occur when accessing a Visualforce page with a standard controller
>   and a custom controller extension.
>
> When a standard controller queries an object for a Visualforce page,
>   it only retrieves the fields from the object that are referenced in
>   the page.  This improves efficiency by not retrieving fields that are
>   not needed by the Visualforce page.
>
> When a custom controller references a field that is not included in
>   the page, the field data is not available, and the error occurs.

Two workarounds to resolve this issue are

- You can add a SOQL query to the custom controller that queries the
  missing fields
- You can add a hidden reference to the field in the Visualforce page.

For example:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!Condition__c.Criterion__c}" rendered="false"/>
```

Reference:-
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?amp;language=en_US&id=000170999&type=1